# side menu reveal on hover

Tags: jquery, hover

I have a simple side menu that is hidden off screen, and I want to reveal it when it hovers in a specific area.  It works well, but if the mouse goes over the menu, it thinks it is out of the area and goes back. Then it will do the opposite of the interaction i want once this happens:

```html
<div class="menu-hover">
  Hover Mouse Here
</div>
<div class="side-menu">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">
    <button id="metro" class="btn">Metro</button>
    <button id="list" class="btn">List</button>
    <button id="grid" class="btn">Grid</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.side-menu {
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    left: -96px;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS:

```js
$(".menu-hover").hover(
  function () {
    var $lefty = $(".side-menu");
    $lefty.animate({
        left: parseInt($lefty.css('left')) < -95 ?
        $lefty.css('left') == 0 :
        -96
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Working code looks like this

```
    $(".menu-hover").on({
    'mouseenter': function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
                    var $lefty = $(".side-menu");
                    $lefty.animate({
                     left: parseInt($lefty.css('left')) < -95 ?
                     $lefty.css('left') == 0 :
                        -96})
                   }
});
$('.menu-hover').on({
    'mouseleave': function(){
        var $lefty = $(".side-menu");
            $lefty.animate({
            left: -96
        })
    }
})
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/glenswift/7UQDM/1/

Comment: The menu does not always go back when the mouse leaves the 'hover area', as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/xtian/rsd8L/

Comment: It seems like i understand your problem badly at the first time. I edit answer and jsfiddle. Be carefull: i change your html code somewhere. I hope this solutions will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

working demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UpaS7/1/)

```
$(".menu-hover, .side-menu").mouseenter(function (){
    $(".side-menu").animate({
        left: 0
    })
});

$('.side-menu').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        left: -96
    })
});
```

Comment: So the menu should slide out when the mouse goes in the area, and then slide back in, then the mouse leaves that area. This code does seem to have this interaction

Comment: @Xtian: Updated my answer. Check and let me know if it's not as expected.